# xp_sendmail: Procedure expects parameter @user

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting **xp_sendmail: Procedure expects parameter @user** when I run xp_sendmail.

How do I associate a given SQLService login profile (SQLMail_Whatever) to outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working with SQLServer2005 (need to use sqlmail for backward compatibility):

1. Login to the machine running the sql server with the login profile you intend to use for mailing
2. Configure an outlook account for that specific account
3. Setup SQLServer and SQLServer Agent services to startup using the same account
4. From SqlSever Management-->Legacy-->SQLMail setup and test outlook as profile name
5. From SQL Server Agent-->Properties-->Alert System check enable mail profile and pick SQLMailand outlook in the dropdowns.

After a service restart xp_sendmail will work.